# IOS Swift UIStackview missing one items

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I use storyboard to create a viewController with a stackview inside a scrollView.

I successfully add items dynamically through outlet the stackview into swift code.

However, one of the shown items disappear....

eg. hard code 5 items
, only 4 shown

4 items , 3 shown

1 item , 1 shown

2 items, 1 shown

```
func loadFakeAnswer(){

    var stack_height:Int = 0

    for index in 0 ..< 3 {
        let answer = StoryAnswer()
        answer.index = index
        stack_answer.addArrangedSubview(answer)
        stack_height = stack_height + answer.answerHeight
    }

    print("ItemCount=" + String(describing:stack_answer.subviews.count))
    stack_answer_height.constant = CGFloat(stack_height + 4 * 6)
}
```

[Stackview config here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gJrw.png)

Comment: Can you share code as I believe the height calculation is wrong. Debug it using tools

Comment: I change to use tableview instead

Comment: `UITableView` is good, but if you have very few data such as here, then you can use UIStackView to reduce code and to increase performance as `UITableView` used `UITableViewCell` which are reused causes rendering and drawing overload. Anyway its ok. Thanks